# How can i hide winmail.dat in Evolution?

Tags: evolution, email

I have a problem with the Evolution e-mail program.

Since a while i get from certain people mails with the attachment *winmail.dat*.

I have installed the `evolution-experimental-plugins` package for the `TNEF plugin` but with no succes.
(The *winmail.dat* attachment still shows up.)

I also have asked if those who send me one of those mail if they could change it in the settings but they refused.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

> TNEF is a program for unpacking MIME attachments of type "application/ms-tnef".

(from the Software Center's description of package `tnef`).

You are supposed to restart your Evolution after installing `evolution-experimental-plugins` ([source](http://www.go-evolution.org/Tnef)) and normally you would see the `winmail.dat` file as well as the unpacked document ([source](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=855440&page=2&p=9401522#post9401522)). This means that it will not be "hidden" or disappear in any way.

Installing the stand-alone `tnef` package will allow to unpack the `winmail.dat` file, once downloaded, thus:

```
tnef winmail.dat
```

([source](http://www.faqforge.com/linux/how-to-open-winmail-dat-files-on-ubuntu-or-debian-linux/)).